# Show $\operatorname{Log}(z^\lambda)=\lambda \operatorname{Log}(z) \bmod 2\pi i$,; an example where $\operatorname{Log}(z^\lambda)\neq \cdots$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

$\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}$**Establish that $\Log(z^\lambda)=\lambda  \Log(z) (\bmod2\pi i$), but give an expample of $z$ and $\lambda$ for which $\Log(z^\lambda)\neq  \lambda \Log(z)$ Assuming that $\lambda$ is both real and positive, determine the setof all $z$ such that $\Log(z^\lambda)=\lambda \Log(z) $. (Hint. For the last part check first that $\lambda \arg(z) $ is an argument of $z^\lambda$ when $\lambda $ is real.)**

I have to prove that $\ln|z^\lambda|+i\arg(z^\lambda)=\lambda(\operatorname{Ln}|z|+i\arg(z))+2\pi k $  but this can not be done by proving that $\ln|z^\lambda|= \lambda \ln|z|$ and that $\arg(z^\lambda)=\lambda \arg(z)$?  But according to what I have read these equalities are not maintained, how could I demonstrate otherwise? Or is this the way?

For the second part, consider $ z = i $ and $ \lambda = 3 $ and the equality is not maintained.

Could you help me with the last part? I do not know how to use the help or how to try it, Thanks

Comment: To understand what is happening, you can write $z = e^{\log(z) + 2i \pi \mathbb{Z}}, z^\lambda \overset{?}= e^{\lambda (\log(z) + 2i \pi \mathbb{Z})+2i \pi \mathbb{Z}}$ (do you see the problem in this last expression ?) Assuming $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$ makes it easier.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Log}{\operatorname{Log}}$
$\newcommand{\Arg}{\operatorname{Arg}}$
Let $z = r e^{i \theta}$, where $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$. Note that $r =|z|$, and $\theta =\Arg(z)$. Consequently, $$\lambda\Log(z) = \lambda \log(r) + i \lambda\theta.$$
On the other hand, $$\Log(z^\lambda)=\Log(r^\lambda e^{i \lambda \theta}) = \lambda \log(r) + i \Arg(e^{i \lambda \theta}).$$
Since, $\Arg(e^{i \lambda \theta}) \equiv \lambda\theta \mod{2\pi}$, we have $$\Log(z^\lambda)\equiv\lambda \Log(z) \mod{2\pi}.$$
For the second part, $\Log(z^\lambda)=\lambda \Log(z) \iff \Arg(e^{i\lambda \theta}) = \lambda \theta$. In other words, $-\pi < \lambda \theta \le \pi$. Equivalently, $-\frac{\pi}{\lambda} < \theta=\Arg(z) \le \frac{\pi}{\lambda}$.